# Do we have any checklist or Guide for mainnet launch on polkadot?

Tags: parachain

Moving forward i need to launch the parachain on polkadot.
Do we have any checklist or Guide for mainnet launch on polkadot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are other resources as well:

- General: https://polkadot.network/launch-parachains/
- Parachains dev: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk
- Parachains guide: https://guide.kusama.network/docs/learn-parachains/
- Testing: https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet
- the link from @kianenigma also mentions a bunch of tools we are using such as `srtool` and `subwasm`, feel free to ask if you need details about those
- Related: In this [directory](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot_network_directory) you will find the list of other chains and thei information (incl. contact information), that may help you as well

Launching a parachain requires some engineering, testing, documentation, marketing, communication, etc...

Are asking about engineering and dev only or do you need information about the full "package" mentioned above ?

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point is checking the release checklist is used in Polkadot e.g. https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/6540.